# Unable to choose vassalization as a war condition?

Tags: stellaris

I'm currently in the mid-game of Stellaris and building up a pretty big empire. From beginning on I had three neighboring, strong empires. I've beaten two of them recently, and forced one to be my tributary and the other one my vassal.

Now I would like to conquer my third enemy...but in the war conditions menu I cannot choose to vassalize him. I can only make a tributary of him. Why is that?

I've also checked some other (small & big empires) and it seems that I cannot vassalize any of them. I can only choose the tributary thing in the war conditions menu. Can I only have one vassal at a time? I've integrating my vassal at the moment: does this affect the vassalization of other empires?

Answer (score 2):

You can vassalize by liberating a group of systems, then vassalizing the resulting empire formed of those systems. The new empire that's created as a result of Liberation has a large bonus to their opinion towards you because of the Liberation, so you should be able to vassalize immediately.

If you have a Defensive Pact or higher (Alliance, Federation) with another Empire, or they are a Protectorate, you can't vassalise that Empire.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the empire you're trying to vassalise is too large? If the required warscore exceeds 100, the system won't let you declare war.